Basic question in understanding the denominator in Bayes with two independent features, but each is dependent on the class
Suppose I have two independent features E1 and E2 distributed over a space (class) H composed of H and not H. I want to find P(H|E1,E2). In this case, E1 and E2 are just independent binary sensors and so each has a certain probability of TRUE or FALSE in H and a different set of probabilities in not H. The denominator of Bayes says to compute P(E1,E2). I compute that using rule of total probability as P(E1,E2|H)P(H) + P(E1,E2|notH)P(notH). However, I have seen this computed instead as simply P(E1)P(E2) (asserting their independence), which can result in a different value. I've done a simulation and it seems like the probability matches what I expect using the rule of total probability and not using P(E1)P(E2).
In particular, I saw this in the Bayesian sensor module of the Home Assistant open source package, where it appeared to compute a successive Bayes by chaining the result of one sensor as the prior of the next sensor, which would result in a P(E1)P(E2) approach.
I might have messed up my simulation, but I've checked it and I think these two approaches are different, so is it really valid to use the P(E1,E2)=P(E1)P(E2) simplified approach? If so, under what conditions is each approach valid?

Saying $E_1,E_2$ are independent means that $P(E_1\cap E_2)=P(E_1)\times P(E_2)$.  That's the definition.

So E1 and E2 are independent of each other, but each is dependent on H such that P(E1|H) != P(E1|not H) and same for E2.

So what?  You asked how to compute $P(E_1\cap E_2)$.  That is $P(E_1)\times P(E_2)$.  You can compute it via $H$ if you prefer, though it just adds work.  It should, of course, give the same value.

Thats the problem Im running into, Im getting different answers depending on how I compute it, so thats where my confusion is coming from. Of course, I could be making a computation error, but I double checked it, but of course, I could have made the same error twice, so Im uncertain.

Well, there's not much we can say as we don't know what your computation(s) look like.   As a wild guess, are you assuming that $E_1,E_2$ are independent even after $H$ is given?  Of course that need not be true.

Thanks. No, in computing E1, Im using total probability there, computing it as P(E1|H)P(H) + P(E1|not H)*P(not H).

Perhaps you would find it easier to write that as $P(E_1\cap E_2)=P(E_1\cap E_2\cap H)+P(E_1\cap E_2\cap H^c)$.

Here is an example. Lets assume P(H) = .5, P(E1|H)=.5, P(E2|H)=.2, P(E1|not H)=.2, P(E2|not H)=.1. Computing P(E1)P(E2) = (.5*.5+.25*.5)(.2.5+.1*.5)=.375 * .15 = .05625. Computing P(E1,E2|H)P(H) + P(E1,E2|not H)P(not H)= (.5*.2*.5)+(.2*.1*.5)=.06, unless I messed up the math (which is very possible).

What does  $E_1*E_2$ mean?  I note that you don't give any information about the conditional probabilities of $E_1\cap E_2$ so you can't use the given data to solve the problem.

Ah yes, sorry, corrected using standard notation E1,E2, which is joint probability, both occurring at same time.

If by $E_1*E_2$ you meant $E_1\cap E_2$, then you are committing the exact error I guessed you were committing.  You write $P(E_1\cap E_2,|,H)=P(E_1,|,H)\times P(E_2,|,H)$ but that assumes independence conditioned on $H$, and you don't know that to hold.

In fact, E1 and E2 are not independent on H. So I think we are in agreement, if the probability of one of the features is dependent on H you cant use this shorthand P(E1)P(E2) you must compute it using total probability.

Anyway, thanks lulu for your comments here.
